# How to remove spacific text from html element

Tags: jquery

I am getting this HTML result from Ajax response with 0 number inside `<ul>..</u/>`.

My response HTML:

```
<section class="gallery-section">
    <ul id="stage" style="display: none;">
        <li data-tags="" class="" data-id="0">
            <a title="image1" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://192.168.1.14/matrix-basement/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/slide-1.jpg"> <img height="162px" width:242px="" src="http://192.168.1.14/matrix-basement/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/slide-1.jpg"> </a>
        </li>

        <li data-tags="" class="" data-id="1">
            <a title="image2" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://www/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/product-1.jpg"> <img height="162px" width:242px="" src="http://www/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/product-1.jpg"> </a>
        </li>

        <li data-tags="" class="" data-id="2">
            <a title="image3" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://www/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/glry-img-1.jpg"> <img height="162px" width:242px="" src="http://www/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/glry-img-1.jpg"> </a>
        </li>

        <li data-tags="" class="" data-id="3">
            <a title="image4" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://www/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/glry-img-7.jpg"> <img height="162px" width:242px="" src="http://www/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/glry-img-7.jpg"> </a>
        </li>
        0 <!-- want to remove this zero -->
    </ul>
</section>
```

Is there any way to remove with jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: there are many ways, but this might be a problem in your retrieval. Why is the  '0' there in your response?

Comment: Fix the cause, not the symptom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work for you :)

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $("ul").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; }).remove();
        }); 
    </script>

    <section class="gallery-section">
        <ul id="stage" style="display: block;">
            <li data-tags="" class="" data-id="0"> 
                <a title="image1" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49a62da0855827bbf64c7ce4f075b5fa/?default=&s=160"> <img height="162px" width:242px="" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49a62da0855827bbf64c7ce4f075b5fa/?default=&s=160"> 
                </a> 
            </li>
            <li data-tags="" class="" data-id="0"> 
                <a title="image1" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49a62da0855827bbf64c7ce4f075b5fa/?default=&s=160"> <img height="162px" width:242px="" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49a62da0855827bbf64c7ce4f075b5fa/?default=&s=160"> 
                </a> 
            </li>
            <li data-tags="" class="" data-id="0"> 
                <a title="image1" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49a62da0855827bbf64c7ce4f075b5fa/?default=&s=160"> <img height="162px" width:242px="" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49a62da0855827bbf64c7ce4f075b5fa/?default=&s=160"> 
                </a> 
            </li>
            0
      </ul>
    </section>
```